# Get rid of duplicated values with basic math

Tags: arithmetic, arithmetic-functions

I've been struggling for some time with this. Is there any way to sum only unique values if you can only use data in table below and:

- Sum
- Average
- number of rows
- number of unique rows

Column 'total sales...' has duplicates and it appears as many times as number of weeks. I can't get rid of duplicate and wonder how to solve this problem.

Desired sum is 122521 + 111696 + 122507 = 356724. If number of rows per week is static I could just divide sum of 'total sales...' per number of week and it would work. As you can see last week has 6 rows, so it won't work.

What I realized is that if I take average of number of rows (first column - in this case average of 4, 4 and 6 equals 4.666666667) it would work. Sum of all 'total sales...' divided by average of number of rows would give me pretty accurate result (1671910 / 4666666667). Is this possible to do it with only these 4 functions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPIh1.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to only use those four "functions"? Based on the image you provided, it looks like you're trying to use spreadsheet software. Does the software you are using not provide this functionality already? E.g., soultions for [MS Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e), [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en), [LibreOffie Calc](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/101374/find-distinct-values-in-a-column-formula-for-calc/).

Comment: total column sum or partial sum ?

Comment: @Brian - I've just prepared sample data in G Sheets but I use software with only these 4 build in functions. It's kind of very simple pivot table. I could count manually number of rows per week and category and then take an average of this but it will not be correct if I filter results. Problem basically is to 'create' equation to count how many rows per group (week, category) exist having only these 4 functions.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee - total column sum is not correct. Please see that there are duplicates. If I could sum unique using these 4 functions above it would work

Comment: I was asking if sum mean't a totsl column sum or a partial sum. if partial it's simple.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee so total column shows total of all categories per week in this city - it's sum of all categories existing in that city and week. Let's say on week 1 in city Houston we have 5 categories (A, B, C, D, E). category column shows only categories which have met some conditions and in week 1 only category A met conditions so column sold show sales for A category splited into A and B column (true and falses) but total sales column shows sales for all columns (A, B, C, D, E) in that city and week.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee (additional info to previous comment) Goal is to have only one value of total column per city and week even I filter this by A, B column. So it's kind of dynamic as if I filter weeks, and columns A, B (show only true, true and false,false total column will show twice) it will show total value as many times as many rows there is. Hope this helps

Comment: I'm asking if sum is a full column sum ... if not  something like A8+E8+I8 should work.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee well, it would work but I can't reference to any cell. I can apply filters and I can either use Sum, Average, number of rows, number of unique rows on all values. I need to write some kind of formula like (sum_all / count_rows)/average. It should be solved this way

Comment: A and B true snd sold not equal to 104 ...